# Real Analysis and infinity

Tags: real-analysis

What is the nature of order relations between infinity?Is

$\infty$ = $\infty$ and hence
$\infty$ $\leq$ $\infty$

or is it simply undefined?

Comment: How do you define $\infty$? It's not a real number...

Comment: You've tagged this as real analysis, so I'm going to assume you're working in the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). In that case, you can make perfect sense of these things.

Answer (score 1):

You must be careful to **define** symbols before you use them, especially if it is not obvious which meaning you are using. For instance there are so many different kinds of infinity in mathematics, including the infinite ordinals, infinite cardinals, real projective infinity, complex infinity and finally the two endpoints $\infty,-\infty$ of the affinely extended reals. Hence the answer to your question is that your "$\infty$" is undefined (precisely because you didn't define it) and your comparison operations on your "$\infty$" are naturally also undefined. However, if you want to ask specifically about the affinely extended reals, then yes in that context $\infty$ is the largest extended real number and whole extended real line is the interval $[-\infty,\infty]$.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to "compactify" the set ${\mathbb R}$ of real numbers. In analysis one usually considers the set $\bar {\mathbb R}:={\mathbb R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$. This enlarged structure $\bar{\mathbb R}$ is not meant to be a field, but certainly is a totally ordered set, insofar as one stipulates $-\infty<x<\infty$ for all $x\in{\mathbb R}$. Furthermore $\bar R$ is a compact topological space, homeomorphic to a finite closed interval, as $[{-1},1]$. A neighborhood base for $\infty$ is the set of all extended intervals ${\mathbb R}_{>a}\cup\{\infty\}$, $\>a\in{\mathbb R}$, and similarly for $-\infty$.